# when I run my testNG class getting error as Cannot instantiate class

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, rest-assured

Please anyone help me to solve this issue....

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.abcd.apitesting.bvt.accBVT
at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:377)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load properties        file:/configure.properties
at com.thed.zeeapitesting.util.Configure.init(Configure.java:26)
```

In eclipse when i run the testNG class am getting error like

My code is like

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import com.jayway.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import com.abcd.abcapitesting.action.Factory;

public class Trigger {

    protected static boolean isInit = false;
    protected static IInfoAction inf = null;
    protected static String Version = null;
    protected static String sessionId = null;
    public static boolean initializeInfoAPI = true;

    public Trigger() {
        init();
    }

    public static void init() {
        if (isInit) {
            return;
        }
        Configure configure = new Configure();
        Version = Configure.getValue("VERSION");
        Factory.init(Version);
        if (initializeInfoAPI) {
            inf = Factory.getInfoActionInstance();
        }
        isInit = true;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = Configure.getValue("abc_BASE_URL");
        RestAssured.port = Integer.parseInt(Configure.getValue("abc_PORT"));
        RestAssured.basePath = Configure.getValue("abc_BASE_PATH");
        sessionId = inf.createSessionId(RestUtil.setRequest()).asString();

    }
}
```

My testNG class is as below

```
public class abcBVT extends Trigger {
    public void Trigger() {
        initializeInfoAPI = true;
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, enabled = enableAll)
    public void bvt1_getManifest() {
        JSONResponseBody = inf.getManifest(RestUtil.setRequest(sessionId));
        status = inf.validateManifest(JSONResponseBody);
        if (status) {
            logger.info("getManifest Executed Successfully...!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm blocked with this.

Comment: read the whole stacktrace: the source of your problem is in `Configure.init(Configure.java:26)`: `Unable to load properties file:/configure.properties`

Comment: Previously it was working and i have not done any changes in configure file

Comment: still something must have changed. You could try to debug the code and find out what is going wrong when loading the properties

Comment: Am not getting ...everything is looking fine while loading property file

Comment: Configure.path = "/configure.properties" ;
  System.out.println(path);
  prop = Util.loadProperties(Configure.path);
  if (prop == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load properties file: " + Configure.path);
  }

Comment: and am loading properties file here,..public static Properties loadProperties(String path) {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  FileInputStream fis = null ;
  try {
   File file = getPropertyFilePath(path); 
   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   properties.load(fis);
   fis.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return null ;
  } finally {
   if (fis != null) {
    try {
     fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     ;
    }
   }
  }
  return properties ;
 }

Comment: Modify your `configure.properties` and save them again so eclipse will rebuild the resource (as build on save is most probably on). This is common issue. Project clean should help as well